# CommandField in last in order when creating dynamic gridview with autogeneratecolumn= true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating gridview dynamically from code behind like following

```
DataTable dt = FromSomesource();

var gridView = new GridView
                   {
                       ID = "Grid_" + grid.GridMasterId
                       DataSource = dt,     
                   };

gridView.RowDeleting += GridRowDeleting;
gridView.RowEditing += GridRowEditing;
//gridView.DataBind(); it doesn't matter if i bind here or later

CommandField cfEdit = new CommandField();

        cfEdit.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
        cfEdit.ShowEditButton = true;
        cfEdit.HeaderText = "Edit";
        cfEdit.CausesValidation = false;

        gridView.Columns.Add(cfEdit);

        ExtendedCommandField cfDelete = new ExtendedCommandField();


        cfDelete.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
        cfDelete.ShowDeleteButton = true;
        cfDelete.DeleteConfirmationRequired = true;
        cfDelete.DeleteConfirmationText = "Are you sure you want to remove this item?"; 
        cfDelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
        cfDelete.CausesValidation = false;
        gridView.Columns.Add(cfDelete);

gridView.DataBind();
```

Problem is that CommandField comes as first column while i wanted it to be last in horizontal order.Can i do it in some easy way without removing existing column and re-adding it in the gridview

Comment: when you create `GridView` dynamically and not set `autogeneratecolumn` to `false`, than default value for this property is `true`, so in your code - first you add column, second adding autogenerated columns

Comment: In the question i have incorrectly put autogeneratecolumn = false isntead of mentioning it as true.Now corrected.
It is true .What i want's that when column are creating automatcially somehow i can control the order of the CommandField.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want concrete?
if you want create gridview dynamically with `autogeneratecolumns=false` then you need set it directly to `false` because default value for this property is `true`, so in this case you must change your code like this

```
DataTable dt = FromSomesource();

var gridView = new GridView
               {
                   ID = "Grid_" + grid.GridMasterId
                   DataSource = dt,     
                   AutoGenerateColumns = false
               };

gridView.RowDeleting += GridRowDeleting;
gridView.RowEditing += GridRowEditing;

/*
    this loop for adding data columns to gridview
*/

CommandField cfEdit = new CommandField();    
cfEdit.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
cfEdit.ShowEditButton = true;
cfEdit.HeaderText = "Edit";
cfEdit.CausesValidation = false;
gridView.Columns.Add(cfEdit);


gridView.DataBind();
```

if  you don't set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false, you can try set `AutoGenerateEditColumn` to `true` and remove code in which you create and add `CommandField` manually

**UPDATE**
try next code

```
DataTable dt = FromSomesource();

var gridView = new GridView
               {
                   ID = "Grid_" + grid.GridMasterId
                   DataSource = dt,     
                   AutoGenerateEditColumn = true
               };

gridView.RowDeleting += GridRowDeleting;
gridView.RowEditing += GridRowEditing;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: it was a typo.I have autogeneratecolumn="true" 
What i want's to say is that i am not creating columns manually

Comment: @KamranShahid so see last lines in my answer

Comment: how it is placing CommandField after the columns binded via gridview datasource?
What's the difference in your code and mine?

Comment: In that way i might not have detail level control over fields.Like i have extended one customfield to get confirmation before delete.

Comment: @KamranShahid so, you want automate generate or custom configure? :-)

Comment: It is autogenerating. Just the positioning of CustomField column is the problem

Comment: @KamranShahid you can handle `OnDataBound` event in gridview and customizing inside it

Comment: How? How can i position the column in last in rowdatabound event.Also in dynamic creeated gridview with rowdaabound there are lots of problem occurs

Comment: not `rowdatabound`, `gridviewdatabound` - i mean not custom position, but you can try and this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41967/discussion-between-grundy-and-kamran-shahid)